# Three.js "THREE.EffectComposer relies on THREE.ShaderPass" issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Hi I'm a big newbie to three.js and I'm trying to use the effect composer function so that I can achieve a bloom effect on my object using UnrealBloomPass.js. Unfortunately I've reached a couple errors which I can't figure out relating to the THREE.ShaderPass in the Effect Composer and I don't know how to resolve them due to my lack of experience. Could someone please help me out?

[image: The Errors I'm getting]

Here's my code:

```js
// Canvas Setup
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canv") 
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
renderer.setSize( width, height );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x111, 1);
    const fov = 100;
    const aspect = width/height;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 5;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
camera.position.z = 2;  
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Geometry Settings
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath("./");
loader.load("assets/model.glb", (gltf) =>{
    root1 = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(root1);
});

loader.load("assets/model2.glb", (gltf) =>{
    root2 = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(root2);
});

// Lighting
const light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x404040);
const light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
light1.position.y = 2;
light1.position.z = 2;
light1.intensity = 2;
light1.shadowDarkness = .1
light2.position.y = -2;
light2.position.z = -2;
light2.intensity = 2;
light2.shadowDarkness = .1
scene.add(light1);
scene.add(light2);


// Controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.maxDistance = 2;
controls.minDistance = 1.3;
controls.maxPolarAngle = 2.5;
controls.minPolarAngle = .5;
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.update();

// Effect Composer 
const composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));
const bloomPass = new THREE.UnrealBloomPass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), 1.5, 0.4, 0.85 );
    bloomPass.threshold = 0;
    bloomPass.strength = 3;
    bloomPass.radius = 1;
composer.addPass(bloomPass);



// Render
function animate() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    root1.rotation.y += 0.002;
    root2.rotation.y += 0.0035;
    controls.update()
    // renderer.render( scene, camera );
    composer.render(delta);
}
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas id="canv"></canvas>

    <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="build/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="build/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="build/EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script src="build/RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script src="build/UnrealBloomPass.js"></script>
    <script src="exp.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the `build/EffectComposer.js` file say? I'll bet you it tries to use elements that you haven't included, like `CopyShader` and `ShaderPass`

Comment: @Marquizzo yes I think your right, viewing in chrome the problem section seems to be this: 
`if ( THREE.CopyShader === undefined ) {`
`console.error( 'THREE.EffectComposer relies on THREE.CopyShader' );`
`}`


`if ( THREE.ShaderPass === undefined ) {`
`console.error( 'THREE.EffectComposer relies on THREE.ShaderPass' );`
`}`

`this.copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );`
`this.clock = new THREE.Clock();`
also sorry for the terrible formatting I'm brand new to stack overflow. you can find this snippet in the original EffectComposer.js file

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to include those in your script tags, then.

Comment: ah ok thank you very much @Marquizzo, i did haft to add `Pass.js` and `LuminosityHighPassShader.js` but overall it works perfectly, again thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `EffectComposer.js` script cant access the correct elements it requires (i.e. `THREE.ShaderPass`).

To solve this problem you just need to import the files that the EffectComposer script requires within your JavaScript/HTML file so that the missing elements required can be read. some files imported this way may require imported elements of their own (i.e. `ShaderPass.js` requires elements from `Pass.js`) so make sure to import them in correct order so that the js files that require additional elements can be read last and the ones that need to be imported into other scripts can be read first.

See the altered code bellow (mainly the HTML file):

```js
// Canvas Setup
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canv") 
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
renderer.setSize( width, height );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x0c023d, 1);
    const fov = 12;
    const aspect = width/height;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 20;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
camera.position.z = 10;  
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Geometry Settings
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath("./");
loader.load("assets/model.glb", (gltf) =>{
    root1 = gltf.scene;
    root1.name = 'world';
    scene.add(root1);
});

loader.load("assets/model2.glb", (gltf) =>{
    root2 = gltf.scene;
    root2.name = 'clouds';
    scene.add(root2);
});
loader.load("assets/house.glb", (gltf) =>{
    root3 = gltf.scene;
    root3.name = 'house';
    scene.add(root3);
});
loader.load("assets/city.glb", (gltf) =>{
    root4 = gltf.scene;
    root4.name = 'city';
    scene.add(root4);
});

// const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
// const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
// cube.scale.y = 3;
// scene.add( cube );

// Lighting
const light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x404040);
const light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
light1.position.y = 2;
light1.position.z = 2;
light1.intensity = 2;
light1.shadowDarkness = .1
light2.position.y = -2;
light2.position.z = -2;
light2.intensity = 2;
light2.shadowDarkness = .1
scene.add(light1);
scene.add(light2);


// Orbit Controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.maxDistance = 12;
controls.minDistance = 1.3;
controls.maxPolarAngle = 2.5;
controls.minPolarAngle = .5;
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.update();

// Hover Controls
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
let INTERSECTED;

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onPointerMove );

function onPointerMove( event ) {
    pointer.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

function hoverObj() {
    raycaster.setFromCamera( pointer, camera );
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
            if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
            console.log("yo")
            var INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            
        }else{
            
        }
    }
}
// Effect Composer 
const composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));
const bloomPass = new THREE.UnrealBloomPass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), 1.5, 0.4, 0.85 );
    bloomPass.threshold = .5;
    bloomPass.strength = 3;
    bloomPass.radius = 1;
composer.addPass(bloomPass);

// Resize Window Function
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
};

// Animation
function animate() {
    // var delta = clock.getDelta();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    scene.getObjectByName(root1.name).rotation.y += 0.002;
    scene.getObjectByName(root3.name).rotation.y += 0.002;
    scene.getObjectByName(root4.name).rotation.y += 0.002;
    scene.getObjectByName(root2.name).rotation.y += 0.0035;
    controls.update();
    hoverObj();
    objrender();
}
// Render
function objrender(){
    // renderer.render( scene, camera );
    composer.render();
}
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas id="canv"></canvas>
    
    <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>
    <!-- required for ShaderPass -->
    <script src="build/Pass.js"></script>
    <!-- both scripts required for EffectComposer  -->
    <script src="build/ShaderPass.js"></script>
    <script src="build/CopyShader.js"></script>
    <!-- required for UnrealBloomPass -->
    <script src="build/LuminosityHighPassShader.js"></script>
    <!-- the main functions i want to use -->
    <script src="build/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="build/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="build/EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script src="build/RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script src="build/UnrealBloomPass.js"></script>
    <!-- main three.js script -->
    <script src="exp.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```